# Connect Local Web servcies from android phone

Tags: android, web-services

I am trying to connect to web services running on my machine(localhost). I have tested from restClient and its working fine. But, I am unable to test them from android application(which I am working on). There seems to be a connection problem.
This is the calling code:

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            String mobileNo = params[0];


            String format = "json";

            try {
                // Construct the URL for Login

                JSONObject requestObject = new JSONObject();
                requestObject.put(MOBILE_NO, mobileNo);

                final String LOGIN_BASE_URL =
                        "http://192.168.42.251:8080/SpringSample/login";

                Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(LOGIN_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .build();

                URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.connect();
                // Request Body
                OutputStream outStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                if (outStream == null) {
                    throw new ConnectException();
                }
                outStream.write(requestObject.toString().getBytes());


                int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == 409) {

                } else if (responseCode == 201) {

                } else {
                    throw new ConnectException();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);

            } catch (ConnectException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);

            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Exception is :

```
 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

Comment: Which catch block is activated? And what is the Exception and message?

Comment: `Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);`. You have three of them. Will you know which one was used? And use e.getMessage().

Comment: If there is no error message. This code just makes a POST request? Or are you attempting to read from the URL as well?

Comment: I debugged the same and its showing the error as : unable to connect(Ip address)  error.

Comment: I am just reading the response status code.

Comment: O. But you will not tell uss the code? And if you have to wait endless then how can you read the response code?

Comment: @ greenapps, its showing unable to connect error.

Comment: Sounds like a timeout error. 1) Is the server running? 2) Are you sure your device is on WiFi? 3) Using the correct IP? 4) Can you check the server logs to see if your request reaches it?

Comment: In which catch block? Exact message with e.getMessage() please.

Comment: Catch block is 'Connect Exception'. I have updated the exception also.

Comment: 1) Server is running. I have tested on restClient. 2)My phone is on wifi and USB tethering on machine.

Comment: It's time that you tell if you use normal wifi or that some kind of usb thethering is involved. How exactly?

Comment: What is `USB tethering on machine'? Does your phone connect with your router or with your pc over wifi? I cannot follow you.

Comment: `I have tested on restClient.`. Where was that client running? And which ip did you use?

Comment: My phone is connected to normal wifi. But I have connected my machine via USB from phone.

Comment: Used ARC from chrome. And I have given the same IP as in code.

Comment: Yes. A usb cable is normal But that has nothing to do with tethering.  Is your pc connected to the same router by lan cable or wifi?

Comment: And where did you use arc from chrome? At your neighbours? Where did it run? WHERE?

Comment: Yes, my PC and phone are using the same wifi connection

Comment: I used ARC on my machine itself.

Comment: Which machine? Pc or phone?

Comment: PC. Also, just now what I saw is, if I give localhost instead of Ip address, when using ARC, it works fine. Otherwise, it shows timeout.

Comment: `Used ARC from chrome. And I have given the same IP as in code` ??? So that was not true? Please be clear.

Comment: There are 2 scenarios: 1) Disconnect wifi network of my pc. And do USB tethering from phone. If I test from ARC, giving IP address or localhost both work.    2)Connect to wifi network on my pc(the same as connected on phone). This time, only localhost works.